# Elasticsearch - difference between cologne and koelnerphonetik encoder

Tags: elasticsearch

We're currently adding phonetic search support to our application by extending our elasticsearch mappings.
As we have a german customer, we want to apply the **cologne phonetic algorithm**.

When I check the available phonetic encoders (see https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/plugins/current/analysis-phonetic-token-filter.html), I see that there are **two encoders which very likely refer to the same algorithm** -> namely "**koelnerphonetik**" and "**cologne**". Both seem to be based upon the cologne phonetic algorithm.

I am a little bit confused by these two encoders as they appear to be the same. Is there a specific reason for having these two encoders? How can I identify which encoder **fits better for me**?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was also interested in the difference between the two as I am trying to capture the maximum information I can from the field I am transforming with phonetics algorithms.

First of all, indeed the two **refer to the same [phonetic transformation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cologne_phonetics)**.

**BUT**, their implementation is a little bit different and lead to different results in some cases.

If you have **one token** in the string you want to analyze, for instance "John", resulting token of the two transformation will be `06`.

However, if you have **more than one token**, for instance "John Doe", results can be different between the two transformation:

- if you use the "[standard toeknizer](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-standard-tokenizer.html)" in ES which splits the string in token: results will be the same between the two transformations:

```json
{
  "tokens" : [
    {
      "token" : "06",
      "start_offset" : 0,
      "end_offset" : 4,
      "type" : "<ALPHANUM>",
      "position" : 0
    },
    {
      "token" : "2",
      "start_offset" : 5,
      "end_offset" : 8,
      "type" : "<ALPHANUM>",
      "position" : 1
    }
  ]
}
```

Because, with the standard tokenizer we go back to the case where you handle one token when you transform the string. String is split by tokens before the phonetic transformation.

- if you use the "[keyword tokenizer](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-keyword-tokenizer.html)" in ES, string is not split in multiple tokens (this tokenizer does almost nothing). **The difference appears here**:

  - `Cologne`: it will transform the string as a single token, resulting token is `062`.
  - `koelnerphonetik`: it will also transform the string as a single token **AND** add token for each token split in the string. Resulting token is a single string separated by "_" -> `062_06_2`.

If you want to try it by yourself, you can [test your analyzer], for instance:

```
POST _analyze
{
  "analyzer": "cologne_analyzer",
  "text":     "John"
}
```

Source Code:

- [KoelnerPhonetik implementation by ElasticSearch](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/blob/feab123ba400b150f3dcd04dd27cf57474b70d5a/plugins/analysis-phonetic/src/main/java/org/elasticsearch/index/analysis/phonetic/KoelnerPhonetik.java)
- [Cologne phonetic implementation in commons-codec used by ES plugin](https://github.com/apache/commons-codec/blob/master/src/main/java/org/apache/commons/codec/language/ColognePhonetic.java)